# Blender to Unity - What to consider?

Tags: unity

I'm (fairly) new to blender but want to create assets to be usable in Unity.

Here are my 3 questions:

1. Which parts should you do in Blender and which in Unity? An example is materials I assume? since they don't translate well/at all into the Unity environment from what I read so far.
2. Which parts of Blender can I "dismiss" if I only create assets for Unity? Like lighting or camera angles.
3. Are the known bugs or "big pitfalls" to consider when using Blender for Unity?

I ask these questions to know on what to focus when learning Blender (I will get the dismissable parts eventually but for now my time schedule is tight so I would like to know which functions I can dismiss for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically dismiss all, except modeling riging/animation and UV mapping.
You won't transfer to unity nothing except that (no camera, no lights). If for material you are using only diffuse with textures (color, normal) it'll transfer well. Only thing to remember is to import to the project textures first and then import .blend or exported .fbx.

Comment: Thx for the quick response, that  sounds good so far. So did I understand it correctly if I need a green slime ball for example I use a green texture from Blender and then I can add the "transparency" and "shinyness" in Unity or do you need some "blank meterials" from blender to achieve such effects?

Comment: IIf you need green slime ball, and you want to make it in Blender, model the slime ball and that's it. If it needs to have only one color (no need for texture for eyes, vains or something) then it's faster to add the shader in Unity and change properties accordingly to your wanting. If you add the material in Blender, you will have to change "transparency" and "shinyness" in Unity anyway and by creating the shader in Unity you can easy add the same shader to other blobs etc. Other then that you also need to consider scale differences in Blender and Unity.

Comment: So I made some progress and come up with another question ^o^ Is there anything to consider when making models for level creation? I mean is there an impact on the perfromance in unity if you use one big model for a lets say a big room level ori s it better to use smaller  individual parts fitted togerher? Does it even mater or its all about how complex these models are wheter big or small regarding performance?

Comment: It's all about tris count and texture size and number. The smaller number of tris, textures and their resolution, the better as far as performance goes. It's not important if you have one model of all town or each house as single model if the tris number is the same. Of course you also need to consider using different levels of details for scene elements that are in different distance from the viewer, so in that context it's better to use different elements as separate models.